# Change Angularjs existing backend to Play 2

Tags: angularjs, playframework-2.0, backend

I have a fully developed Angularjs frontend app (with the routes and everything set up) and would like to change the current backend to a Play 2 Java. What is the best approach to display the existing html files from Angular in Play? I have found a few examples of how to connect the routes, but I would rater not create an index.scala.html file as I would like to have the two frameworks separated as much as possible and having Play only working as backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to dynamically generate views from Play using Twirl and you just want to serve your HTML static files publishing them as [assets](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Assets) is the way to go. By default assets are designed to provide resource like CSS or JS files but nothing prevents you from serving ordinary HTML views as well.

Simply put your index.html in the **public** directory and modify the **conf/routes** files so it can handle all requests:

```
GET  /*file        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

This way your index.html will be accessible at *www.yourdomain.com/index.html*. Remember to put this line as the last mapping in the file as it matches all possible URLs. Other services should be declared above it.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend putting catch-all route like this to the _root_ routing level, of course your advice is correct, anyway it's fair enough to keep asset route withe the common `/assets/...` prefix, especially if the Play app will have more features then just keeping the single ng-app in the future.